# what do you do if you have test anxieties?

Tags: exams, disability

What is the best way to resolve test anxieties?

Comment: Why disability as a tag?

Comment: Would you say you have really good note taking habits?

Comment: @Buffy Anxiety and related mental health issues are treated as disabilities at my university; students with a professional diagnosis are eligible for exam accommodations such as extra time and/or a lower-distraction environment.  The tag is appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

Cognitive behavioral therapy, conducted by a licensed mental health professional, does reduce test anxiety.  This is usually used in severe cases.

Students who are told that it is normal to be anxious will feel less anxious and perform better.  Students who are told that being anxious will help them get a better grade also get a better grade than students who are not told that.

Reflecting on why education is important helps students overcome their anxiety.

These strategies are based on experimental evidence.

Comment: Do you have an action item for the OP, or just the theoretical background?

Comment: Action item: Cognitive behavioral therapy, conducted by a licensed mental health professional.

Answer (score 2):

A few suggestions that helped me a lot:

- Review the material after each class. Do some exercises to make sure you've got it clear. Having solid understanding eases off nervousness.
- If you have, say, a Chem exam on Thursday, study for that exam at most up to Tuesday. You won't learn anything new on Wednesday anyway, just tire out and get nervous. Yes, you may study for the Math exam on Friday on Wednesday. But go to bed early.
- If the nerves get to you, do something else: go for a walk, do exercise, cook, do something that requires your attention.
- Be careful with what/when/how much you eat. Some food or drink that disagrees with your stomach (even a bit) will only make anything worse.

Comment: `Thuesday` Did you mean Tursday? ;)

Comment: @6005 Tuesday... but I edited it.

Comment: +1. Study continuously so that you don't need to cram. Give your mind a rest and your body a workout before an exam. Go in alert and well oxygenated.

Answer (score -1):

1. Know the material very well.  "Overlearn."
2. Do lots of practice tests on your own, under test conditions (no breaks, no lookups, time limit, etc.)

Comment: Re (1), don't overdo it. It is detrimental. Learn until you feel confident, then stop. And (2) is a good idea, but sometimes hard to organize on your own.

Comment: If your tests are anything like music or sports in terms of the stakes, nervousness, etc. I think you will find overtraining can be helpful.  Lowers the stress when mastery is felt.  Also, while there are some small fraction of students that know the material completely and then overdo it, that is probably very rare versus those who say "got it", but really don't when the heat is on and the bullets are flying.

Comment: See also this question from same poster:  https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/143815/how-do-you-approach-your-professor-if-you-do-not-understand-or-know-how-do-do-th (I hadn't even looked at it, when I responded.  But it is a rather telling illustration of how material mastery MAY be more the issue rather than performance anxiety.)

Comment: Furthermore, 2 is very easy to organize. Buy a drill book on Amazon, compose a mini-test.  Segregate yourself.  Take the test with strict time limit.  Self grade it (you have the answers at a minimum, often worked solutions in drill guides, as well as the text to refer to for methods).  Is it a Euclidean perfectly congruent replication of a test?  No.  Is it a damned good, and simple, and efficacious, approximation of one?  Hell, yes.

Comment: For what it's worth, I liked all your suggestions.  Consider mine additions.  But for students that lack mastery (and ESPECIALLY for students that don't even come close to mastery), 1 pertains.  If you know it cold, cold, it is easier. Yes, sometimes you can perform in the clutch without it.  But it's harder and more stressful for sure.

Comment: For those who actually have mastery, but still poor performance under "event" conditions (probably a small fraction), method 2 is helpful.  It gets easier to do anything stressful (e.g. landing on a carrier), the more times you practice it.  And even approximate practice can be incredibly helpful versus facing the stress more cold.  (We are not computers, psychology applies.)